# Make Child control more Opaque than Parent

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a Page like in the Xaml below which i want to use like a ModalDialog.

The Problem is that when I Pop the Dialog up, that the Opacity of the second Grid which holds the Content is not changed back to 100% and I see from the Page where it is Popuped the underlying controls. For more Detail see the Screenshot.

Is there a way that I can change back the Opacity of the second Grid to 100% that no control behind it can see through?

For completneness I have added the Code which i'm using to bring up the Popup.

**ModalDialog Xaml:**

```
<Page>
    <Grid x:Name="RootPanel" Background="{StaticResource LucentBlue}" Opacity=".75">
         <Border >
              <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Height="300" Background="{StaticResource PremiumBlue}" Opacity="1">

              </Grid>
         </Border>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Code Behind Hosted Page:**

```
private Popup _saveDialog;
private void SaveSettingsCommandLogic(object obj)
{
    ModalDialog dlg = new ModalDialog();
    dlg.CloseRequested += DlgOnCloseRequested;
    _saveDialog = new Popup();
    _saveDialog.Child = dlg;
    _saveDialog.IsOpen = true;
}
```

[image: Error Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution in metro :

Please remove the `Opacity` property of both the elements and from the code behind of the ModalDialog class use the following code:

```
    public ModalDialog()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Color color = Color.FromArgb(150,255,0,0);
        RootPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }
```

The method `FromArgb` is used to specify the transparency red green and blue values respectively and can rancge from 0-255 .. please test according to ur convinience :)

Comment: U can also set the BackGround property in the xaml in argb format

ie:

Background="#AARRGGBB" Where AA-> will range from 0->99 and RRGGBB are the hexadecimal color code.